# selecting from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to select **all rows** from multiple tables(20 tables) but it isn't working for me, can some show me to select the first two? The tables have **duplicate column names** if that matters. I have read the manual and it says I can use `JOIN` but I couldn't get it.

What I tried:

```
stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1, table2 where firstname LIKE ? ORDER BY id desc");
stmt->bind_param('s', $fname);
stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Joins are like so:

```
SELECT `something` FROM `table1` t1 JOIN `table2` t2 ON joinitem.t1 = joinitem.t2 ...
                                  ^--------table 1's id---------- ^    ^--column name
```

Comment: @amdvb yes I was just putting that in for example.

Answer (score 0):

if you need data from each table that has a relationship with the other table provide the link in your `WHERE` clause

```
"SELECT * FROM table1, table2 where table1.id = table2.id AND firstname LIKE ? ORDER BY id desc");
```

If you want to mass select data from tables that doesn't have relationship to one another you can use a `UNION` but all the columns selected need to be the same type and column count needs to match

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where firstname LIKE 'x'
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table2 where firstname LIKE 'x'
```

Comment: Both tables must have the same number of columns to allow such UNION

Comment: `same type and column count needs to match` i don't know if you didn't read it or ...

Comment: the tables doesn't have any relationship and the columns doesn't match

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have column `id` both in table1 and table2. Try to specify the table name explicitly in ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1, table2
WHERE
    firstname LIKE ?
ORDER BY
    table1.id desc
```

If you are sorting by table2.id, use it instead. If firstname is present in both tables, specify the table name in WHERE statement.